# Django is overwriting the existing model

Tags: python, django

I have an abstract model class userabstract which has fields id(primary key), name(char field) and email(email field).
I am inheriting this class in two classes user, usertemp. After signing up, i want the data to be stored in usertemp. When user clicks on confirmation mail then that data will be transferred to user class.
But whats happening is, whenever someone signs up, usertemp model is updated instead of creating a new one. Same thing is happening with user class

Here is the code for models and views

```
class UserAbstract(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True, default=1)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='NAME', max_length=100, default='')  # Field name made lowercase.
    email = models.CharField(db_column='EMAIL', max_length=100, default='')  # Field name made lowercase.

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class User(UserAbstract):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name ;
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'User'

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Validation(models.Model):
    key = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    key_data = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    create_time = models.DateTimeField()
    expire_time = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key_data

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class UserTemp(UserAbstract):
    validation_key = models.ForeignKey(Validation, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='+', default='')  # Field name made lowercase.
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.validation_key.key_data
```

views.py

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormTemp(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            primary = form.cleaned_data['email']
            try:
                qdict = {}
                qdict['email'] = primary
                user = UserTemp.objects.get(**qdict)
                if user.verified==True:
                    return HttpResponse("Account already exists")
            except:
                pass

        email = form.cleaned_data['email']

        signer = hashlib.sha256()
        signer.update(primary)
        validation_key = signer.hexdigest()

        confirm_key = request.build_absolute_uri('/signup-confirm/')+'?key='+validation_key

        send_mail('Confirm Your Mail', confirm_key, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [email,])

        valid = Validation(key_data=validation_key, create_time=datetime.now(), expire_time=datetime.now()+timedelta(days=30))
        valid.save()

        argsdict = {}

        argsdict['name'] = form.cleaned_data['name']
        argsdict['email'] = form.cleaned_data['email']
        argsdict['validation_key'] = valid
        argsdict['verified'] = False


        usertemp = UserTemp(**argsdict)
        usertemp.save()
        return HttpResponse("Confirmation mail sent")
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Invalid Data')
else:
    return HttpResponse('What are you doing here ? Tresspass')
```

The valid.save() is working fine and every time validation key is being saved but the usertemp contains only one model and that is the most recent one.
When i tried `force_insert=True` then its telling me that duplicate entry exist with same primary key. As you can see, the primary key field `id` is AutoField then why django not creating a new model when i am writing `usertemp = UserTemp(**argsdict)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you've given your `AutoField` a default value. You're telling Django to assign that field the value `1` if you don't provide it, which means that you keep writing rows with the same `id`.

So just get rid of that default.

The broader point to understand is that `defaults` are a Django-level feature, while `AutoField` is a database-level feature. From the perspective of the database, there's no difference between explicitly assigned column values and Django default column values.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot, I had been searching for my solution for more than 2 hours.